# How to get unmatched elements from two hive arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql

I'm looking for a hive function and query to get the unmatched elements from two arrays in Hive. Let's say arrays are

```
A = ["Hello", "earth"]
B = ["Hello", "mars"]
Expected output is ["earth", "mars"] or ["mars", "earth"]
```

Another example

```
A = ["Hello", "world"]
B = ["Hello", "world", "!"]
Expected output is ["!"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode both arrays in subqueries, FULL JOIN subqueries and filter not matched records, then aggregate them using collect_set to get array.

Demo:

```
with your_data as (
select array ("Hello", "earth") A,
array("Hello", "mars") B
)

select collect_set(coalesce(A.element_A,B.element_B)) as result
from
(select element_A 
 from your_data d lateral view explode(A) e as element_A
)A

FULL JOIN 

(select element_B 
 from your_data d lateral view explode(B) e as element_B
)B 
ON A.element_A=B.element_B

WHERE A.element_A is NULL OR B.element_B is NULL
```

Result:

```
["earth","mars"]
```